# How would I go about Transfering data between JAVA and PHP?

Tags: java, php, sockets, transfer

I have a java application that has information that I need to display on a webpage, sorta like a chat room, The way I'm currently doing it is by having the java application listen for connections on a specific port and then I have a PHP script that connects every second to update the information listed on the page, What I'm trying to find out is there a better way of doing this? I haven't done anything like this before so sorry If this method is really stupid, I'm just looking for the best way to accomplish this. All constructive comments are welcome.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I'm doing this over TCP and I do not have access to MySQL so I can't store anything In a database then have the PHP script go and retrieve it..

Comment: This is how most chats work, someone is bound to listen the other speak (IRC for example, where the client is waiting for the server to talk). I think your solution is fine, you can even keep the connection active so the server can send its data as soon as possible.

Comment: @Djon I've done **some** work with sockets in the past but not much, I don't know how I could keep the connection alive with PHP. The current way I'm doing it is by having JQuery load the PHP script every second and then update the results based on what the PHP script returns. Do you know of any examples that you could link me to? I would greatly appreciate it.

If there is no good method of doing this with PHP then I guess I'll just keep my current method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know PHP, the way I see it would be: having the Java application listening as the server (that's what you have), and then connect once with PHP. Then I suppose PHP has a blocking read function (that will wait until it receives data), so you can loop this function and it will read as soon as the server sends something. But I see nothing wrong in doing that every second, I'm just comparing to how IRC works.

Comment: @Djon I'd have to re-write some stuff since the current way I'm doing it involves the client connecting to the server and the server just sends the recent 10 messages, Then I just sort the old messages from the new ones and update the list. I'll wait to see what others have to say and If I find nothing else I'll give your idea a shot.

Comment: I think it really depends on what you need, IRC is for real time chat, so perharps updating a webpage every second is fine. If it involves too much work, don't change it unless it improves something. As for your original question, I don't know any other way to transfer data between two distant applications.

Comment: @Djon The only issue I've noticed so far is that If you are trying to type something into a field and it is constantly doing these updates it sometimes makes it so the keys don't get entered and you have to push them again, Not really sure how I could go about solving this issue though.. Currently I just have it setup to not update the data while the user is typing into the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends strongly on the flow, when should the communicate? If PHP needs data from Java then just do a call and parse the data back in xml's. Else if it is a lot like a chat, there should be a way to socket it, although I have never tried it.